# Spring social Insufficient permission

Tags: java, spring, linkedin-api, spring-social

I try to get Company by using Spring Social Linkedin API. In settings i allow my application to all permission. See picture below:

[image]

I had invoked methode like this:

```
linkedIn.companyOperations().getCompany(17754);
```

and recived exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException: Insufficient permission for this operation.

Connect with linkedin account is correct, but try to use methode like:

> companyOperations(), jobOperations(), groupOperations()

giving me exception.

What i could doing wrong? Any ideas?